# npm outdated and npm update doesn't work

Tags: node.js

I want to check if my modules are Latest

i do: `sudo npm outdated`

and I have this results

```
Package              Current  Wanted  Latest  Location

oauth                  0.9.9   0.9.9  0.9.10  twit > oauth
require-all            0.0.3   0.0.3   0.0.8  mysql > require-all
bignumber.js           1.0.1   1.0.1   1.3.0  mysql > bignumber.js
request               2.27.0  2.27.0  2.30.0  facebook-chat > node-xmpp > node-xmpp-client > request
through                2.2.7   2.2.7   2.3.4  facebook-chat > node-xmpp > brfs > through
```

then i do this:`sudo npm update`
but if I repeat `sudo npm outdated` i have the same results...
also if I do for example
Info:

```
Package              Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
oauth                  0.9.9   0.9.9  0.9.10  twit > oauth
```

Then Update

```
sudo npm update oauth
```

Then

```
sudo npm outdated oauth
```

My Result:

```
Package  Current  Wanted  Latest  Location
oauth      0.9.9   0.9.9  0.9.10  twit > oauth
```

Comment: Have you put specific package versions in your `package.json` file (e.g. `~0.11.8` instead of `*`)? I doubt that NPM update your packages if dependencies are too strict.

Comment: No, I have not edited file..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your project is actually as up-to-date as it can be currently.

NPM won't simply install the `Latest` version of a package unless [that version is also `Wanted`](https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-outdated.html).

> The resulting field 'wanted' shows the latest version according to the version specified in the package.json, [...]

And, for each that you listed, the `Wanted` and `Current` versions already match.

```
Package              Current  Wanted ...

oauth                  0.9.9   0.9.9 ...
require-all            0.0.3   0.0.3 ...
bignumber.js           1.0.1   1.0.1 ...
request               2.27.0  2.27.0 ...
through                2.2.7   2.2.7 ...
```

An attempt to force `oauth` to its current `Latest` of `0.9.10`, for example, would actually be considered `invalid` as [`twit` has `0.9.9` listed exactly](https://github.com/ttezel/twit/blob/9cda40625f2d3fb01d2db1ff006f44f1d13ce9fd/package.json#L14-L16):

```
"dependencies": {
  "oauth": "0.9.9"
},
```

```
$ npm ls
...
└─┬ twit@1.1.11
  └── oauth@0.9.10 invalid

npm ERR! invalid: oauth@0.9.10 ...\node_modules\twit\node_modules\oauth
```

Comment: thanks for reply ! twit use oauth 0.9.9, but this dependence is on 0.9.10 version, which is not updated until Twit does not require it .. force oauth to 0.9.10 version may cause errors...is this want you mean ?

Comment: @Barno Yeah. `twit` will have to update its `"dependencies"` to allow `oauth@0.9.10` to be installed under it. Though, since `twit` is an open-source project, the author(s) may be welcome to a pull request with that update, provided all of its tests still pass.

Comment: I never use sudo with npm, should I be?

Comment: @pixel67 [It's suggested to use `sudo`, but not required](https://www.npmjs.org/package/npm#permissions-when-using-npm-to-install-other-stuff).

Answer (score -3):

Check your package.json may be your packages or there there.
try to install package with --save and try it will work

example :
npm install underscore@1.5.0 --save
now try 
npm outdated